# Problems with some textures in XNA

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7, sketchup, xna-4.0

I have made a model using Sketchup, and have tested rendering it using Blender and it looks great.
However loading it in XNA has two problems.
1. One of the textures becomes see-thru not entierly transparent but items below on the inside of the model is visible (this is not the case in blender).
2. I have a rounded part on the model that is divided into smaller parts and the texture gets out of sync (the posisioning is all wrong).

I have tested exporting the model to 3ds and then use blender to save it as fbx (to eliminate any problems with Sketchup).
I have also tried using AutoDesks FBX Converter, same problems =(

I'm using myModel.Draw(World, View, Projection); to render the model.

Any suggestions?

/Jimmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Sounds like a backface culling issue try this

device.RenderState.CullMode = CullMode.None; (try the CW and CCW variants)

also make sure the depth buffer is enabled

2) This may be similar problem to an issue I had with blender when you copy the bones try the gModel.CopyBoneTransformsTo(transforms); as well as gModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

Comment: Hi Couldn't find RenderState, perhaps not present in XNA 4.0 or WP7?   And the no2 sugestions didn't work. However I added:   GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;   (I'm guessing that enables the depth buffer? :P)   And it worked =D Thanks   Thats two days I'll never get back ;)

Comment: cool glad that helped looks like xna 4 is quite different from version 3.1 this might help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx